# Rails 3: Form getting submitted twice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, formtastic

I am developing a Rails application that has forms generated using formtastic. 
I am developing & testing locally - that is - on localhost:3000 w/ Ruby-1.9.2, Rails-3.0.1, jQuery and AJAX.

Below is a sample screen output of the problem I am seeing. My forms are getting submitted twice within 1 second of each other. I can't understand why this is happening. I see this issue w/ all requests - including GET.

> 1. Started POST "/businesses/6/edit_balance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-07 **02:31:47** +0530   Processing by
>      BusinessesController#edit_balance as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>      "authenticity_token"=>"zcWH08sV8kPbAYy7JQX64Cu2e1i/kEB1AB4x5a08CO8="
> 2. Started POST "/businesses/6/edit_balance" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-07 **02:31:48** +0530   Processing by
>      BusinessesController#edit_balance as JS   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>      "authenticity_token"=>"zcWH08sV8kPbAYy7JQX64Cu2e1i/kEB1AB4x5a08CO8="

And so I am wondering whether I am making a basic programming error. If yes, then could you please suggest some solutions that I could try.

Comment: could you solve this? I currently have the same problem

Answer (score 9):

I had this same problem right after deploying to Heroku... I pre-compiled my assets, and all of a sudden I was getting double AJAX submissions.  I guess I somehow ended up with duplicate javascript files in public/assets.

To fix the problem I just deleted my entire public/assets directory.

Comment: Amir, thanks. Ata Ga'on! I've tried precompiling then cleaning the assets and it didn't work. But simply deleting the public/assets directory worked! Thanks! (Just did `rm -r public/assets/`)

Answer (score 1):

If you're submitting the form with Javascript, try to set the submit button to be disabled when the form is submitted. With jQuery it would be something like this (not tested):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
  $(this).find(input[type='submit']).attr("disabled", "true");
  ... // submit form via AJAX
  return false;
});
```

Comment: form.attr("action", …) sets only the "action" attribute for the form and therefore determines whereto the form will be submitted, but doesn't actually submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks PolarBlau.. Let me try your suggestion..

Apnediving: Below are the bits of code that 1. create the form (form partial) 2. define the dialog that houses the form (dialog partial) and 3. the JS that attaches an action to the form.

Form Partial (credits_form)

```
- f.inputs :name => 'Edit Credits' do 
  = f.input :numeric_input_1, :label => 'Amount', :as => :select, :collection => [1000,2000,3000] 
  = f.input :boolean_input_1, :label => 'Add Credits'
  = f.commit_button :label => 'Submit'
```

Dialog Partial

#edit-credits-dialog

- @user_input = UserInput.new

```
 = semantic_form_for @user_input, :remote => true do |f|     
 = render :partial => 'businesses/credit_form', :locals => {:f => f}
```

JS Code

```
$.getJSON('/businesses/' + id + '/load_credits', function(data) { 
    var form = $('#edit-credits-dialog form') ; 

    form.attr('action', '/businesses/' + id + '/edit_balance') ; <-- seems to be happening twice
    $('#edit-credits-dialog').dialog('open') ; <--- happens once 
}) ;
```

Comment: Disabling the submit button does not seem to work. I still see 2 POST requests for every one click.

Comment: Disabling the submit button does not seem to work. I still see 2 POST requests for every one click. Is it possible that the second request happens because the browser did not receive acknowledgement for the first? I also realized that I removed the respond_to block from my controller and replaced it with just a render :json. Could it be that the respond_to is important and prevents duplicate processing? If its neither of the above 2 possibilities, then I am screwed because I don't have a third idea.

Comment: OK, I figured it out.. There is a problem with my javascript files. I was binding the same 'click' event twice on the same object. And apparently - starting with jQuery-1.4.2 - its possible to do that. Currently I am by-passing the issue by doing $(obj).unbind('click', handler).bind('click', handler). But I have a whole evening of reorganizing code ahead of me. Thanks though to everyone for their inputs

Comment: Which two javascript files were interfering? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: I was just getting the same problem, I was binding clicks with '$(document).on('click', '#button', 'myData', myFunction); '.  Replaced that with $('#button').click(myFunction(myData));